# Android convert DateFormatSymbols to int

Tags: android, string, date, int

I know this thing has been dealt with many times but I can not solve.
I'm viewing the month as a string with this code:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            final String month = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault()).getMonths()[position].toUpperCase();
            TextView tvMonth = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_mese);
            tvMonth.setText(month);
```

I would now like to spend a month as a whole. I tried using SimpleDateFormat but to no avail.
thanks

Comment: what do you mean by **"spend a month as a whole"**?

Comment: sorry, I was wrong. I need to convert the month (name)string to(number) Int

Comment: why don't you simply use `position + 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're question was a bit unclear, so I apologize beforehand if I've misinterpreted it. I'm assuming that you want the number of the month (i.e. 1 would be January, 2 would be February, etc).

The easiest thing to do (as @waqaslam also mentioned), would be to take the value of position, and add one to it. So, this would be the last line in your snippet of code:

```
 int monthAsWhole = position + 1;
```

An alternative, albeit a much more complicated one, is to do the following.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        final String month = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault()).getMonths()[position].toUpperCase();

        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMMMMMM", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(month);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        int theMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        TextView tvMonth = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_mese);
        tvMonth.setText(month);
```

Here, SimpleDateFormat will parse you're final string month as a date variable. Then, a Calendar variable will use date, and calling the Calendar.MONTH constant of that calendar variable of will essentially return an integer of you're month variable. For January, it will be zero, for February, it will be 1, etc.

Since the String variable, month, is not inherently a String containing an integer, it cannot be parsed as such. The most practical and plausible way to convert a String like *FEBRUARY* to a String is by converting it into a numeric representation of the month in question.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I repeat my problem: I have the month as a string formatted like this:`String month = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault()).getMonths()[position].toUpperCase();`

now I want to convert it to an integer, how do I?
thanks